# Spiral vertices animations

Tags: animation, objects

How do I animate vertices of a spiral? I can animate location and rotation of the object, but not the movement of individual vertices.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!. I had to enable the "AnimAll" Add-on in the user preferences. Then I clicked insert for each vertex I wanted to animate.

Comment: Good attempt. Have you tried to animate a curve/spiral's vertices using the **hooks** though?